Infinitesimal rank 1 update to eigendecomposition
Consider a Hermitian matrix $H$ for which we know the decomposition $Q \Lambda Q^\ast$.
Let $H'= H + \epsilon~x x^\ast$ for a small $\epsilon$.
What is a good way of computing the decomposition of $H'$ in a way that ensures $||Q - Q'|| = o(1)$?
My thinking is:
let $y = Q^\ast x$, then $H' = Q (\Lambda + \epsilon~ y y^\ast) Q^\ast$
Now $\Lambda + \epsilon ~ y y^\ast$ is Hermitian and nearly diagonal, so all we need is to efficiently find that decomposition, ensuring that the eigenvectors are chosen to the identity.
My contention is that a few rounds of the QR algorithm will achieve that. However, I'm not sure if there are guarantees for $\epsilon$ small enough that we converge to the decomposition where the eigenvectors are as close as can be to the identity matrix. We're also not making use of the fact that we're dealing with a rank 1 update which could simplify things.
Can we show that this work, is there a better way?

maybe you can get inspiration from the Sherman-Morrison formula
